# Fastest route to last key of dict in Tcl

Tags: dictionary, tcl

Let's say that I have a Tcl dictionary. I want the fastest way to get the last entered key of the dict (not the value).
Theoretically, I could use:`lindex [ dict keys $dict ] end` 
Does anyone know anything else, which is faster?

Comment: That'd probably be about the fastest; the data structure has the information to do it faster, but nobody's really wanted the operation before as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty fast:

```
% set data {a 1 b 2 c 3}
a 1 b 2 c 3
% proc p1 {} {dict get $::data [lindex [dict keys $::data] end]}
% time {p1} 100000
1.87782 microseconds per iteration
```

But you can shave off about a microsecond by remembering the last key:

```
oo::object create mydict
oo::objdefine mydict {
    variable data last
    method add args {
        lappend data {*}$args
        set last [lindex [dict keys $data] end]
    }
    method getLast {} {
        dict get $data $last
    }
} 

% mydict add a 1 b 2 c 3
c
% time {mydict getLast} 100000
0.82731 microseconds per iteration
```

Documentation:
[create (method of `oo::class`)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/class.htm),
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm),
[lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm),
[method (object configuration subcommand)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/define.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[oo::objdefine (object definition command)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/define.htm),
[oo::object (class of objects)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/object.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[time](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/time.htm),
[variable (object slot subcommand)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/define.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing `[lindex $data end-1]` to be faster.

```
tclsh last.tcl
time_list : 1.0693949999999999 microseconds per iteration
time_dict : 279.470543 microseconds per iteration
```

last.tcl

```
set data [dict create]
for {set i 0} {$i < 10000} {incr i} {
        dict set data "key_$i" $i
}

set time_dict [time {
        set last_key [lindex [dict keys $data] end]
} 1000]


set time_list [time {
        set last_key [lindex $data end-1]
} 1000]

puts "time_list : $time_list"
puts "time_dict : $time_dict"
```